# Instance is not GlassFish Server 3+ or it is not running, Deployment error: GlassFish Server 3+ Server cannot start. Port is occupied

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I keep getting these errors

Using netbeans 7.2.1, glassfish 3.1

I looked at numerous posts for this problem, but nothing seems to work

Shanged port in \glassfish\domains\domain1\config to 9999,
after that first project deployment and running was fine, but after that the same project and others gave again these errors at deployment.

running netstat -aon | find ":80" | find "LISTENING" in cmd gives no results or sometimes java.exe process pid

what else can I do to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Are you stopping the GlassFish server before starting it again?

Comment: should I stop GlassFish server after each project run?

Comment: If you need to start another one afterwards.

Comment: stopping server before each run indeed solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Please checkmark my answer if it helped/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start a new instance of Glassfish 3 server, you must stop the old one to free up the port. Only one instance may run at a time.